# typeorm: saving an entity with many-to-many relationship ids

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Is it possible to save an entity with many-to-many relation ids?

suppose I have following `Project` Entity with many-to-many relationship to userGroups table.

```
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  name: string

  @RelationId((project: Project) => project.userGroups)
  userGroupIds: number[]

  @ManyToMany(type => UserGroup, userGroup => userGroup.projects)
  @JoinTable()
  userGroups: UserGroup[]
}
```

Since ids of the userGroups table are mapped to `userGroupIds` property of the Project class via `@RelationId` decorator, I thought I could save a new Project entity with userGroupIds like this:

```
let prj = new Project()
prj.name = 'foo'
prj.userGroupIds = [1, 2, 3]
prj.save()
```

but the above code only creates a project record... (no record is created on project - userGroups many-to-many relation table)

Comment: I think you should create the usergroup first, and add the created usergroup to project.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You mean if i have 3 existing records(id=1,2,3) on user groups table, we need to create 3 instances of UserGroup entities from those records and add them to project entity?

Comment: yes, you can do like that.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Would be better if we could simply pass ids tho...

Comment: nope, because you don't always know the id, in test yes but in production you don't know

Comment: Also unable to save relation on existing entities this way `prj.userGroupIds = [1, 2, 3]`. With 1,2,3 being ids of existing entities. I am surprised this do not work. This `prj.userGroup = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]` work but is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not get any of the above answers to work. Turned out I needed to enable `cascade` on the relation, as described by the documentation.

```js
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  name: string

  @ManyToMany(type => UserGroup, userGroup => userGroup.projects, {
    cascade: true // this is the important line
  })
  @JoinTable()
  userGroups: UserGroup[]
}
```

Then you can do:

```js
let prj = new Project();
prj.name = 'foo';
prj.userGroups = [1, 2, 3].map((id) => ({ ...new UserGroup(), id })); 
prj.userGroups = [1, 2, 3].map((id) => ({ id })); // alternatively
prj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

**entity**

```js
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  name: string

  @ManyToMany(type => UserGroup, userGroup => userGroup.projects)
  @JoinTable()
  userGroups: UserGroup[]
}
```

**resolver**

```js
const input = {
    userGroupList: ['id1' 'id2', 'id3'];
};

const project = new Project();
project.name = 'Name of the Awesome Project';
project.userGroups = Promise.resolve(input.userGroupList.map(id => ({ id })) as UserGroup[]);
project.save(project);
```

`@RelationId`, you don't need to use this decorator. In TypeORM, when you add your `@ManyToMany()` and `@JoinTable()` decorators to `@Entity`, it automatically creates a table and creates the `userGroupId` and `projectId` cells within the table.

When you instantiate a new Project entity, **TypeORM** also shows the relations as properties if any.
We make use of a *synthetic* `Promise.resolve()` to assign a value to the `project.userGroups` relations. Then we complete the relation by sending the project object into the `.save()` method.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add existing entities to a new entity, you can do so as follows:

Given:

```
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  name: string

  // You shouldn't need this
  // @RelationId((project: Project) => project.userGroups)
  // userGroupIds: number[]

  @ManyToMany(type => UserGroup, userGroup => userGroup.projects)
  @JoinTable()
  userGroups: UserGroup[]
}
```

To add new entries:

```
idsToAdd = [1,2,3] // Assume these already exist
let prj = new Project()
prj.name = 'foo'
prj.userGroupIds = idsToAdd.map(id => ({...new UserGroup(), id})) // Convert each of the ids into the proper entity.
prj.save() //  Typeorm will ignore the other fields and only update the Ids, as you expect.
```

An alternative would be to `map` each `id` to `{id: id}`, but typescript is likely to complain about that mapping, since there are probably other fields that are required in the entity/class.

Note: You may need to enable `cascade` on the entity, especially if you're doing more than just linking ids. See [here](https://typeorm.io/many-to-many-relations#saving-many-to-many-relations) for the docs on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of your suggested approaches worked - at least with TypeOrm.

Comment: Sorry, I tweaked my answer a bit to account for your scenario, but I did not need to use cascade. Perhaps you were saving more than just the ID?